Deterministic (programmatic) guidline for function inlining when targetting modern x86 processors?
(IMO) Cons when not inlined:

call is unconditional branch (jump) with stack manipulation, and the x86 instruction table specifies it needs 4 uops/inst. and has reciprocal throughput of 2 for Zen4 uarch. The function requires "argument passing" upon each function call, and the function itself requires "fixed" prologue and epilogue for its own stack and registers, while the inlined function may reduce the argument passing as well as prologue/epilogue.

Non-static version of function cannot be evaluated at compile time when used by other "module" (executable or library).

If the compiler decides to not to inline a static inline function, the compiler has to generate separate object code and link to it statically. Each separate object requires own phyiscal memory when loaded, not like extern functions where all processes uses it on a single read-only shared memory region.

When the code inside a function is, when compiled, "smaller" (both in code size and overhead) then the function calling cost listed in 1., then it is generally good to force inlining (except if that code needs to be link dynamically all the time), like:
static __always_inline __attribute((sysv_abi))
int evaluate_this_program_quality() {
    /*
     * `mov eax, 0` has 5 bytes, and `call evaluate_this_program_quality@PLT`
     * is also 5 bytes.
     */
    return 0; 
}



(IMO) Cons when inlined:

It increases code size and the overhead of instruction cache miss. Each invocation cannot be shared-cache, and if the target processor uses BTB (branch target buffer) or etc. for branch prediction, since the branching address is all different, it will affect the performance of branch prediction badly.

For modern processors, due to deeply pipelined main memory like DDR5 compared to old ones, and due to the fact that internal timing constraints of modern processors get significantly relived as the fabrication improves, the ratio of cache miss latency in whole execution gets increased significantly. For example, there are many recent reports that compiling -Os option is better at time-wise performance compared to -O2, while higher than -O3 is always worse due to increase code footprint. Also, nowadays there is LTO (link-time optimization) that can inline codes (+ etc.) within the other compiled objects. Then, should I not use inline hints at all?
For example:
/* Inside library's source code (*.c) */
static thread_local pid_t _tid __attribute__((tls_model("initial-exec")));
#define likely(expr) __builtin_expect(!!(expr), 1)
pid_t fast_gettid() { return likely(_tid) ? _tid : (_tid = gettid()); }
/* Inside library's public header (*.h) */
pid_t fast_gettid();

/* Inside library's source code (*.c) */
thread_local pid_t _tid __attribute__((tls_model("initial-exec")));
/* Inside library's public header (*.h) */
extern thread_local pid_t _tid;
#define likely(expr) __builtin_expect(!!(expr), 1)
static __always_inline pid_t fast_gettid() { return likely(_tid) ? _tid : (_tid = gettid()); }

How "small" code is actually good to be used as static __always_inline function? Is fast_gettid() "small" enough, or not?
Another example:
static __always_inline __attribute((pure)) const char *
filename(const char *restrict path) {
  if (path) {
    const char *const restrict __basename = __builtin_strrchr(path, '/');
    return likely(__basename) ? __basename + 1 : path;
  }
  return path;
}

Is this function "small" enough for modern processor? Should I separate constant-exprssion version? Should I maintain this as __always_inline, or change to just inline and let the compiler to decide, or remove inline hint and let LTO optimize it?
It's been a while I have searched a deterministic (programmatic) way to decide upon this issues, or at least well-known, best-effort principles regarding these. I know the answer will depend on circumstances, but I just cannot bear myself without knowing the baseline opinion.

What problem do you want to solve?

As you state at the end of your question, this is opinion-based. It depends entirely on what you care about, there's no single objective best way. That being said, unless you've profiles performance, why do you care, what are the needs driving you to optimize?

The baseline opinion is let the compiler deal with it. The folks working with the compiler are always dealing with requests and use cases and code samples and processor manufacturer information and timing experiments, and they have built what knowledge they can into the compiler. You are not going to do any better than that for the general case without a great deal of work, replicating what they have already done.

Beyond that, modern processors are so complicated that there will always be cases where any set of not unreasonably large rules yields an imperfect result. Making a routine inline or not can push code over some cache line boundary, causing something else to be slow, some odd quirk of using a register to pass an argument can move other things around, causing them to be fast, and so on. It is simply beyond our ability to predict all the effects in diverse circumstances.

You appear to want an expert's opinion instead of relying on your own judgement. If so, use inline (which uses the opinion of the crafters of compiler's optimizer) instead of __always_inline (which overrides that opinion with your own).

Thank you all for all your comments! @0___________ It is more like software engineering issues about how to distribute the API. Usually without LTO (which requires compile-time settings and LTO-enabled static objects (archive)), inlining is not possible without static inline function definition included in the public header. But then, if you are going to put your function there, heuristic inlining by compiler introduces 1-3. issue in the above article. Then, should I give up using inline hint at all and use (and make others to use) LTO all the time, or maintain static inline functions?

IMO, “con when not inlined 3” is a spurious objection.  Had the function been inlined N times, the object file would have N copies of the code, albeit optimized.  You can't really object, therefore, to one copy of the code and N calls.  And you can create a non-static inline function and have one copy of that called from all the files where the function is not inlined.

@JonathanLeffler But isn't each individual executable (or library) loaded need separate read-only page for that sysmbol, at least single copy each?

I just leave it to the compiler, under the assumption that whoever wrote the optimization stuff knows a bit more about the target architectures than I do. Of course, I don't know how many millions of filename() calls you are making per second, but seeing how you're cluttering your code with compiler-specific shenanigans just makes me shudder.

Consider a program built from source files S1.c, S2.c, S3.c.  There's a static inline function F1 defined in header H1.h included by each of the source files.  S1.c makes N1 calls to F1, S2.c makes N2 calls to F1, and S3.c makes N3 calls to F1.  If F1 can be inlined, there will be N = N1 + N2 + N3 copies of the body of the function in the 3 object files.  If F1 cannot be inlined, there will be 1 copy of the function in each object file, plus N call sequences.  Since you were happy to have N copies of the function, you can't really complain about size with 3 copies and N call sequences.

Further, if you defined a plain inline (not static inline) function in H1.h, and one of the files — S1.c for concreteness — contained extern inline RetType F1(...);, then there would be one copy of F1 in S1.o that would be called N times from the three object files.  That reduces the overhead still further.  I don't particularly recommend this technique — using static inline is so much simpler.  But I don't think you can complain about the overhead when F1 is not inlined given that you'd have been happy to have N copies of the function if it had been inlined.

Echoing what others have also said: IMO, if you want to use inline as a hint to the compiler, by all means do so.  Don't worry about the performance — in terms of size or speed — unless you can demonstrate by measurement that there is meaningful degradation.  And if there is, revert to omitting inline.  If functions are declared static (without inline), the compiler will often inline them anyway if the function is only called once, even if the inlined function is large.

But with or without inline, isn’t static required for compiler inlining in code generation stage? So if there is no deterministic guideline to determine inlining or not, how can one decide to share function definition (source) to all compilations of target objects or not? Should I just not use static(just for inlining where visibility constraint does not exist)/static inline, and let the LTO to care all?

No — static is not required for functions to be inlined.  If the header contains inline int F1(int a1) { ...definition of function… }, the compiler may use that function definition to inline the function.  If it doesn't inline, you somewhere need extern inline int F1(int a1); — with the header included — to generate an actual, externally visible function F1.  Then the code should work correctly, regardless of whether F1 is actually inlined by the compiler.  There isn't a simpler rule of thumb than "declare functions static inline in the header file that defines them".  It works.

Let the compilation toolchain worry about the rest — whether or not you use LTO.  If you have evidence that this doesn't work, come back with concrete examples.  But until then, my impression is that your worries are similar to worrying about how many angels can dance on the head of a pin.

Earlier, you asked whether "each individual executable (or library) loaded need[s] a separate read-only page for that symbol, at least [a] single copy each"?  If the function is inlined, you're going to get a separate copy of the code for each invocation of the function mixed in with the rest of the code for the calling functions.  If the function is not inlined, you'll get one copy of the code for each object file.  If you don't like the idea of repetition in the object files, don't inline the function.  Or let LTO do its stuff — it may or may not be able to help.

@JonathanLeffler If the header contains inline int F1(int a1) { ...definition of function… }, the compiler may use that function definition to inline the function. I was meant more like, “then which function should I put its definition to the header?”. It is probably not a good design to supply ALL function definitions via the header, right? That means, if I develop a library, then in order to have inlining in the linked executable/library, I have to supply all definitions through the public header, for the compiler to decide whether to inline or not.

You only put the implementation of the functions that you want inlined in the consumers' code in the public header.  If you don't want to expose the implementation to the consumers of your library, you don't make the function inline in the public header.  Your choice.  Generally, you should only make a few small and important functions visible for inlining and keep the rest as regular functions.  Using inline is an optimization.

For the most part, you should be able to drop inline without breaking anything — which is certainly feasible for static inline functions and only requires a bit more care if you use plain inline functions. For plain inline functions, you replace the function definition in the header with a regular extern declaration, and you ensure that one of your source files contains the (non-inline) definition of the function.
